# Decomposition for a shear transform $(x,y) \mapsto (x+y, y)$

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry, linear-transformations, matrix-decomposition, plane-geometry

In theorem 15.14 of *Transformation Geometry — An Introduction to Symmetry*, to prove that an affine transformation is a product of strains, George E. Martin takes a shear mapping

$$\begin{cases}x'=x+y \\ y'=y\end{cases},$$

"casts a spell", and the mapping decomposes into a composition of a similarity, a strain, and a similarity, arising from the decomposition of its matrix
$$\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 1 \\ 0 & 1\end{pmatrix}=
\begin{pmatrix}\frac{5-\sqrt{5}}{20} & \frac{5-3\sqrt{5}}{20} \\ -\frac{5-3\sqrt{5}}{20} & \frac{5-\sqrt{5}}{20}\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix} \frac{3+\sqrt{5}}{2} & 0 \\ 0 & 1\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix} 2 & 1+\sqrt{5} \\ -(1+\sqrt{5}) & 2\end{pmatrix}.$$
Is there a way to arrive to this decomposition (either of the matrix or of the mapping) naturally?